# Pro*C unable to read parameter passing from korn shell script

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I have a korn shell script which will pass 4 parameters to a Pro*C file

The syntax of the korn shell script are below:

```
###  $command_dir/proc_file_name / $deptid $txdate $pid

###  I hardcode the values for testing
$command_dir/proc_file_name / 701 20170109 201701094444001
```

The syntax of the Pro*C file:

```
....

main(argc, argv)
int argc
char *argv[];

username.len=strlen(argv[1]);
strncpy((char*)username.arr, argv[1],username.len);
username.arr[username.len]='\0';

deptid.len=strlen(argv[1]);
strncpy((char*)deptid.arr, argv[1],deptid.len);
deptid.arr[deptid.len]='\0';

txdate.len=strlen(argv[1]);
strncpy((char*)txdate.arr, argv[1],txdate.len);
txdate.arr[txdate.len]='\0';

pid=atoi(argv[4]);

printf("\n%s\n", username);
printf("\n%d\n", deptid);
printf("\n%d\n", txdate);
printf("\n%d\n", pid);

....
```

I found that the values of the parameters were not I put. 
Please help...
Many Many thanks

Comment: Please make sure to check basic syntax before asking questions on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same array index of `1` for username, deptid, and txdate.  Correct that and you would be good.

Accessing `argv[1]` etc., without checking `argc` isn't a good practice.  When invoked without arguments, your code will result in a core dump.

Also, I don't think your code has the right syntax.  Can you please paste the code that compiles?